# Merging 2 panda dataframes, extracted through web scraping

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, merge

I am trying to build a database on US universities. I have been using Beautiful Soup and Pandas to do so, but have encounter difficulties as there were several tables to scrap per page. In order to reunite the data extracted from two tables, I tried to use .merge(), but haven't succeeded at all.

My code is as follows:

```
# Connecticut
url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_Connecticut'
soup=bs(requests.get(url).text)
table = soup.find_all('table')

#Extracting a df for each table
df1 = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df1.rename(columns = {'Enrollment(2020)[4]': 'Enrollment', 'Founded[5]':'Founded'}, inplace = True)

df2 = pd.read_html(str(table))[1]
df2=df2.drop(['Type','Ref.'], axis=1)

df_Connecticut=df1.merge(df2, on=['School','Location','Control','Founded'])
df_Connecticut
```

I have tried to do it with other states, but still encounter the same problem:

````
 Maine
url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_Maine'
soup=bs(requests.get(url).text)
table = soup.find_all('table')

#Extracting a df for each table
df1 = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df1=df1.drop(['Type[a]'], axis=1)
df1.rename(columns = {'Location(s)': 'Location', 'Enrollment (2019)[b]':'Enrollment'}, inplace = True)
df1 = df1.astype({'School':'string','Location':'string','Control':'string','Enrollment':'string','Founded':'string'})

df2 = pd.read_html(str(table))[1]
df2=df2.drop(['Cite'], axis=1)
df2.rename(columns = {'Location(s)': 'Location'}, inplace = True)
df2 = df2.astype({'School':'string','Location':'string','Founded':'string','Closed':'string'})

df_Maine=df1.merge(df2,  on=['School','Location','Founded'])
df_Maine```
````

I am complete beginner in Python.

Comment: did you try **concat** instead of **merge** ?

Answer (score 0):

Would agree with @Clegane that you may mean `concat`, cause merge indicates that there have to be values in both that could be matched.

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
```

|  | School | Location | Control | Carnegie Classification | Enrollment | Founded | Closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Albertus Magnus College | New Haven | Private(Catholic) | Masters university | 1793 | 1925 | nan |
| 1 | Asnuntuck Community College | Enfield | Public | Associates college | 2388 | 1969[6] | nan |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 50 | Silvermine College of Art | New Canaan | Private | nan | nan | 1951 | 1971 |
| 51 | Wilcox College of Nursing | Middletown | Private | nan | nan | 1908 | 1997 |

Otherwise you should address the `how` to make an outer join:

```
df_Connecticut=df1.merge(df2, on=['School','Location','Control','Founded'], how='outer')
```

Comment: `concat` didn't work because I ended up with 2 columns of schools, 2 of location... but the `how` to make an outer join worked fine ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Not sure if you used the example `pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example pertaining to the two states you mentioned. Of course, you can include other states as well in your list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
big_df = pd.DataFrame()
states = ['Maine', 'Connecticut']

for x in states:
    r = s.get(f'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_{x}')
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
    df.columns = ['School', 'Location', 'Control', 'Type', 'Enrollment', 'Founded']
    df['State'] = x
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(big_df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    School  Location    Control Type    Enrollment  Founded State
0   Bates College   Lewiston    Private Baccalaureate college   1964    1855    Maine
1   Beal University Bangor  Private (for-profit)    Associates college  229 1891[5] Maine
2   Bowdoin College Brunswick   Private Baccalaureate college   1969    1794    Maine
3   Central Maine Community College Auburn  Public  Associates college  3746    1963[6] Maine
4   Colby College   Waterville  Private Baccalaureate college   2150    1813[7] Maine
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
61  University of New Haven West Haven  Private Masters university  7587    1920    Connecticut
62  University of Saint Joseph  West Hartford   Private (Catholic)  Masters university  2975    1932    Connecticut
63  Wesleyan University Middletown  Private Baccalaureate college   3599    1831    Connecticut
64  Western Connecticut State University    Danbury Public  Masters university  6463    1903    Connecticut
65  Yale University New Haven   Private Doctoral university 14910   1701    Connecticut
66 rows × 7 columns
```